# How to track dynamically updating code using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, onchange, event-listener

How do I track dynamically updating code on a website?

On a website there is a part of the code that shows notifications. This code gets updates frequently, and I would like to use selenium to capture the changes.

Example:

```
# Setting up the driver
from selenium import webdriver
EXE_PATH = r'C:/Users/mrx/Downloads/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=EXE_PATH)

# Navigating to website and element of interest
driver.get('https://whateverwebsite.com/')
element = driver.find_element_by_id('changing-element')

# Printing source at time 1
element.get_attribute('innerHTML')

# Printing source at time 2
element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

The code returned for **time 1** and **time 2** is different. I could of cause capture this using some time of loop.

```
# While loop capturing changes
results=list()
while True:
    print("New source")
    source=element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    new_source=element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    results.append(source)
    while source==new_source:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Is there a smarter way to do this using selenium's **event listener**?
            new_source=element.get_attribute('innerHTML')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wait by selenium way with `WebDriverWait`, selenium provide a method `.text_to_be_present_in_element`, you can try following approach.

First you need following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
```

Try the bellow code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('changing-element')

# Printing source at time 1
element.get_attribute('innerHTML')

#something that makes the element change

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, 'changing-element'), 'expected_value'))

# Printing source at time 2
element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

But if it isn't found, it will return an `TimeoutException` error, please handle with `try/except`

Comment: Thanks. It looks similar to my approach. I will try it out later today, and get back to you.